# Titles of questions are too large on a mobile device

Tags: bug

There seem to be a regression with font size on softwareengineering.stackexchange, when displayed on a mobile device. Here's a side by side comparison between SE.SE and SO. In the first screenshot, the title of the questions is too big.

[image]
[image]

The issue can also be reproduced on a PC, by going to *Inspector* and activating *Responsive design mode*. By default, Firefox shows responsive design for 320×480, where the issue is present, with the font size being 20.9231px on SE.SE instead of 20.9231px on SO.

I haven't checked all the SE sites, but the sites such as photo.stackexchange.com or unix.stackexchange.com don't have the problem.